# xdg-open doesn't handle percent encoded "file:///" urls with LXDE

Tags: debian, lxde, xdg-open

I noticed that xdg-open doesn't handle percent encoded urls. For example, these lines will succeed (provided the files exist):

```
xdg-open "/home/sashoalm/Has Spaces.txt"
xdg-open file:///home/sashoalm/NoSpaces.txt
```

But this one will fail:

```
xdg-open file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt
```

**Edit:** This is my version of xdg-utils

```
 sashoalm@aspire:~$ apt-cache policy xdg-utils
xdg-utils:
  Installed: 1.1.0~rc1+git20111210-6+deb7u1
  Candidate: 1.1.0~rc1+git20111210-6+deb7u1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.0~rc1+git20111210-6+deb7u1 0
        500 http://ftp.bg.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**Edit 2:** This is the trace:

```
sashoalm@aspire:~$ bash -x xdg-open file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt 
+ check_common_commands file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt
+ '[' 1 -gt 0 ']'
+ parm=file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt
+ shift
+ case "$parm" in
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ unset XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL
+ '[' 0 -lt 1 ']'
+ xdg_redirect_output=' > /dev/null 2> /dev/null'
+ '[' xfile:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt '!=' x ']'
+ url=
+ '[' 1 -gt 0 ']'
+ parm=file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt
+ shift
+ case "$parm" in
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ url=file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ '[' -z file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt ']'
+ detectDE
+ unset GREP_OPTIONS
+ '[' -n LXDE ']'
+ case "${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP}" in
+ DE=lxde
+ '[' xlxde = x ']'
+ '[' xlxde = x ']'
+ '[' xlxde = x ']'
+ '[' xlxde = xgnome ']'
+ '[' xlxde = x ']'
+ DEBUG 2 'Selected DE lxde'
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ return 0
+ '[' x = x ']'
+ BROWSER=www-browser:links2:elinks:links:lynx:w3m
+ '[' -n :0 ']'
+ BROWSER=x-www-browser:firefox:seamonkey:mozilla:epiphany:konqueror:chromium-browser:google-chrome:www-browser:links2:elinks:links:lynx:w3m
+ case "$DE" in
+ open_lxde file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt
+ echo file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt
+ grep -q '^file://'
++ echo file:///home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt
++ sed 's%^file://%%'
+ local file=/home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt
+ echo /home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt
+ grep -q '^/'
+ pcmanfm /home/sashoalm/Has%20Spaces.txt
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ exit_success
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ exit 0
```

Comment: I could not reproduce this. Which version of the xdg-utils package are you actually using? You can get it with `apt-cache policy xdg-utils`.

Comment: I could really not reproduce this. For me, this works with exactly the same package version. I suggest you to fill a [Debian bug report](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting).

Comment: @jofel You mean that xdg-open works for you with URLs that have %20 (that encodes a space)?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: @jofel I added the trace, if that's any help.

Comment: thanks, this was the needed information. xdg-open behaves differently depending on the used desktop environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using an LXDE desktop environment, xdg-open opens `file://` URLS with the `pcmanfm` program. It strips the `file://` part of the URL and calls `pcmanfm` with the remaining part, since pcmanfm supports only normal paths as arguments, not URLs.

`xdg-open` does not do any other replacements, so `%20` is not translated into a space. This is a bug (feel free to open a bug report for this in Debian).
A fix is described below.

For other desktop environments, the open programs support correctly file:// URLs.

---

**Workaround**:
Unset some environment variables, so that xdg-open uses the generic open handler which supports all needed replacements:

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP= DESKTOP_SESSION= xdg-open "/home/sashoalm/Has Spaces.txt"
```

**Bugfix:**
Copy the xdg-open script to /usr/local/bin (so that it is not overwritten by upgrading your system) and add the line

```
file="$(printf "$(echo "$file" | sed -e 's@%\([a-f0-9A-F]\{2\}\)@\\x\1@g')")"
```

to the xdg-open script above the `# handle relative paths` comment line.

**Bugfix 2:**

Or simply replace replace `detectDE()` with:

```
detectDE()
{
    DE=gnome
}
```

Comment: Actually, I just replaced `detectDE()` with `detectDE()
{
 DE=gnome
}`, and now everything's working again - including magnet links (they weren't working as well).

Comment: `detectDE()
{
    DE=gnome
}` Awesome trick Wooooooooooo!